# Problems with OpenCV warpPerspective with transparent images

Tags: python, opencv, transparency

I'm trying to change the perspective of a fake glasses image with OpenCV, but the transparent parts and opacity get lost. Resulting image has no transparencies.
I want to change the perspective in order to stamp the resulting image over another image.

Can I do this with OpenCV?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import cv2

glasses = cv2.imread('fake_glasses.png')

RES_SIZE = (500,640)

pts1 = np.float32([[  0,  0], [599,  0],
                   [  0,208], [599,208]])
pts2 = np.float32([[ 94,231], [354,181],
                   [115,316], [375,281]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(glasses, M, RES_SIZE)
cv2.imwrite("rotated_glasses.png", rotated)
```

[image: fake_glasses.png (with transparent parts]

[image: mask.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the image incorrectly, dropping the transparency layer. This is easy to verify -- print the shape of the image after you load it.

```
>>> img1 = cv2.imread('fake_glasses.png')
>>> print(img1.shape)
(209, 600, 3)
```

When not specified, the flags parameter of [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) is set to `IMREAD_COLOR`. According to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80a1b482916f4ffe34f0b90550f267fd896) this means

> If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.

Instead, you should use `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`

> If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).

With this change, the image loads correctly, including the alpha plane.

```
>>> img2 = cv2.imread('fake_glasses.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
>>> print(img2.shape)
(209, 600, 4)
```

Comment: Is there a way to "stamp" the transformed image into another image?
I'm trying to do it with cv2.warpPerspective but I can't get to the point.

Should be something like:

`final_image = cv2.warpPerspective(glasses, M, RES_SIZE, face_image, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)`

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (614,500,3) (640,500,3)

Comment: This is my code: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8kqD8em1Hp-WTVpTEE2dVI1YTg)

Comment: Close but no cigar :) ... now images are blended, but with wrong colors. Glasses are red, but blended are black [link](http://imgur.com/a/LsWqo)

Comment: @xabi Odd, this [variant of your script](http://pastebin.com/40aRrCTA) produces [this result](http://i.imgur.com/e9yTmBr.png) on my machine (tried both OpenCV 2.4.11 and 3.1.0).

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell what version it really is based on that, but seems pretty old, since they [fixed that version display bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1804) sometime in 2012 (and [merged](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_attic/commit/061c7aed0c1f89445736bbbf4119079ce267b8b0#diff-1f98d22cee58d7695217d8cc7557fca4R1013) it to trunk soon after that). | At this point I don't really see how you could end up with the black glasses...

Comment: Testing in other linux machine with clean opencv and works like a charm.